# Cannot use 'Enter' as input to 'Merge' because 'Enter' is in a while loop. See info log for more details

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have a question about Tensorflow. Part of my code is:

```
cell2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu)
rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell2, X, dtype=tf.float32)
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
Cannot use 'Enter' as input to 'Merge' because 'Enter' is in a while loop. See info log for more details.
```

If I run again, I have the similar message:

```
Cannot use 'Enter_1' as input to 'Merge_1' because 'Enter_1' is in a while loop. See info log for more details.
```

I guess the problem is my input `X`. `X` is not a placeholder variable and I am not going to feed it with some tensor, instead, it is a constant tensor of size `[1,3,25]`. What I want to do is just getting the output of RNN (`rnn_outputs`) and compare the output with some other tensor.

Can anyone help me with problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I still cannot solve the problem; but I found if you disconnect the kernel and re-open and re-run the program, this issue will be gone.